# Validating for valid html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I wanted to conduct a validation in javascript for some input and return valid if it is a valid Html tag.

Is there any easy way using JQuery to do that? If not then is there any way I can do it using Regex?

Thanks:)

Comment: Check for jQuery plugin library for validation plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Someone [had to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make an array of valid tags then use jQuery.[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)(tag, validTags);

```
var validTags = ["<html>","<body>","<div>"];
var valid = function(tag){
    return $.inArray(tag,validTags);
}
var x = valid("<body>"); //evaluates to true
```

Here is a regex to get you started if you want to accept any tag name with only letters.  It's not been thoroughly tested, but is designed to accept one or more case-insensitive letters. If you also want to allow numbers, add in a \d between the brackets too e.g. **[A-Za-Z\d]**.

```
var validTag = /^<\/?[A-Za-z]+>$/;
var valid = function(tag){
  return validTag.test(tag);
}
```

See [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for more regex help.

Comment: That is true but I wanted to see if there is a way to regex it. Actually I have not been clear..... If it is a tag then also that is fine.....does not have to come from W3C approved Tag collection that html supports. If it is <XYZ or <XYZ/> that's fine. Does not have to be HTML. But it certainly has to be a tag....

Comment: That sounds more like XML though I'm not positive.  But I see the array wouldn't work.

Comment: Does that tag name have any restrictions?  Just letters or numbers?  Is a number allowed as the first character?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method for this a long while back. I've since implemented it into being an `Element` property. Use the code below to test validity of an Element's tag as simple as:

```
ele.isValidTag();
```

So, for instance, if you wanted to see if `blink` was valid, and if not, insert a CSS to make `<blink>` tags actually blink, you could do:

```
if (!document.createElement('blink').isValidTag()) {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        style = document.createElement("style");
    /* Standard (Mozilla) */
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }"));
    /* Chrome & Safari */
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@-webkit-keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }"));
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("blink { -webkit-animation: blink 600ms infinite; animation: blink 600ms infinite; text-decoration: blink; }"));
    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

> ***NOTE:***
>     Accepts parameter of `true`, to include *obsolete* tags. OR use `-1` to automatically bypass *obsolete* check all together.

```
/*  Copy && Paste   */
Object.defineProperty&&!Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty("isValidTag")?Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype,"isValidTag",{value:function(b){if(this.tagName){var c="acronym applet basefont bgsound big blink center dir font frame frameset hgroup isindex listing marquee multicol nextid nobr noembed noframes plaintext spacer strike tt xmp".split(" "),a=this.tagName;return a.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)?!1:-1!==b&&-1!==c.indexOf(a.toLowerCase())?b||!1:"[object HTMLUnknownElement]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement(a))}return!1}}):Element.prototype.isValidTag=function(b){if(this.tagName){var c="acronym applet basefont bgsound big blink center dir font frame frameset hgroup isindex listing marquee multicol nextid nobr noembed noframes plaintext spacer strike tt xmp".split(" "),a=this.tagName;return a.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)?!1:-1!==b&&-1!==c.indexOf(a.toLowerCase())?b||!1:"[object HTMLUnknownElement]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement(a))}return!1};
/*  Copy && Paste   */
```

---

> Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty && !Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty("isValidTag") ? Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "isValidTag", {
        value: function(b) {
            if (this.tagName) {
                var c = "acronym applet basefont bgsound big blink center dir font frame frameset hgroup isindex listing marquee multicol nextid nobr noembed noframes plaintext spacer strike tt xmp".split(" "),
                    a = this.tagName;
                return a.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/) ? !1 : -1 !== b && -1 !== c.indexOf(a.toLowerCase()) ? b || !1 : "[object HTMLUnknownElement]" !== Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement(a))
            }
            return !1
        }
    }) :
    Element.prototype.isValidTag = function(b) {
        if (this.tagName) {
            var c = "acronym applet basefont bgsound big blink center dir font frame frameset hgroup isindex listing marquee multicol nextid nobr noembed noframes plaintext spacer strike tt xmp".split(" "),
                a = this.tagName;
            return a.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/) ? !1 : -1 !== b && -1 !== c.indexOf(a.toLowerCase()) ? b || !1 : "[object HTMLUnknownElement]" !== Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement(a))
        }
        return !1
    };

if (!document.createElement('blink').isValidTag()) {
 var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
  style = document.createElement("style");
 /* Standard (Mozilla) */
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }"));
 /* Chrome & Safari */
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@-webkit-keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }"));
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("blink { -webkit-animation: blink 800ms infinite; animation: blink 800ms infinite; text-decoration: blink; }"));
 head.appendChild(style);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Hi <blink>I</blink> should be <blink>Blinking</blink>!
</p>
```